# why can't you use List<string> instead of string[] when using Directory.GetDirectories("c:\\")?

Tags: c#

I'm just curious as to why I have to use the `string[]` when using `Directory.GetDirectories()`

```
string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories("c:\\");

foreach (var dir in directories)
{
     Console.WriteLine(dir);
}
```

Why can't I use

```
List<string> _directories = new List<string>();
        _directories = Directory.GetDirectories("c:\\");
```

Comment: If you really want a list, you can call the LINQ extension `Directory.GetDirectories("c:\\").ToList()`

Comment: You can also initialize your list with the array: `_directories = new List<String>(directories);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `GetDirectories` returns a `string[]`, basically.

Anyway, you can:

```
List<string> _directories = new List<string>(Directory.GetDirectories("c:\\"));
```

...or:

```
List<string> _directories = Directory.GetDirectories("c:\\").ToList();
```

Comment: +1 for decent explanation rather than condecension like from the other guys

Comment: @Trust me - I'm a Doctor wasn't condescending, unless his comment above was modified, but +1 for an explanation and code samples.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `Directory.EnumerateDirectories()` Anyway - as it will only enumerate the directories, instead of filling up a whole array - which will use less memory.

from MSDN:

The EnumerateDirectories and GetDirectories methods differ 
    as follows: When you use EnumerateDirectories, you can start 
    enumerating the collection of names before the whole collection 
    is returned; when you use GetDirectories, you must wait for
     the whole array of names to be returned before you can access 
    the array. Therefore, when you are working with many 
    files and directories, EnumerateDirectories can be more efficient.

(unless you really need a filled array)

EDIT:

So - to answer the question more specifically - if you wish to return a List<> type, you're better-off doing:

```
var dirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories("c:\\").ToList();
```

As this will avoid the 'array' step of the conversion.

Comment: +1.  Doesn't directly answer the quetion, but gives a nice alternative.

Answer (score 3):

[Directory.GetDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getdirectories%28VS.71%29.aspx) has been around since .Net 1.1 before generics such as [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28VS.80%29.aspx) were introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Because its the return type of the method obviously.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer/118694#118694

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is performance. If you know how many items you'll have beforehand (and you do for searches), you can preallocate a normal array and fill it in, without the double growth strategy penalty `List<>` uses.

Once you have your basic `string[]` object, you can easily feed it to a list and append to it if you really need to. Going the other way would incur a performance penalty for the most often used use cases.

Comment: You can initialize a `List` with a capacity if you know the size ahead of time, so no, that cost doesn't need to be there.

Comment: I guess but an array still has to be simpler for the GC to handle since it never changes during the lifetime of the program right?